# Selecting Number of Id's using loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 5 different id's as below:

```
<div id ="box1"></div>
<div id ="box2"></div>
<div id ="box3"></div>
<div id ="box4"></div>
<div id ="box5"></div>
```

Is there any way to call each id using for loop in javascript?

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
//i want to call those ids each at a time. At first box1, then box2...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    var id = "box" + i;
} // box1, box2, box3, box4, box5
```

You will then be able to use `id` to manipulate those elements.

If you want to get the element and act on it:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    var id = "box" + i;
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial, assuming every `id` follows the same format:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var element = document.getElementById('box'+(i+1));
    // Do whatever you want to with element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through each div and get a reference to it so you can do stuff with it. It'll work as long as the divs are numbered in order and there are no breaks in the numbering (i.e., if you have box1, box2, and box3 it will read all 3, but if you have box1, box4, box5 would only read box1):

```
var ct = 1
while(document.getElementById('box' + ct)){
     var cur_div = document.getElementById('box' + ct)

     //do stuff here

     ct++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div")).forEach(printId);

function printId(element, index) {
  console.log('[id' + index + '] = ' + element.id);
}
```

```html
<div id ="box1"></div>
<div id ="box2"></div>
<div id ="box3"></div>
<div id ="box4"></div>
<div id ="box5"></div>
```